# Spring standalone injecting properties

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a standalone application in which I need to inject properties. I have defined these properties in a properties file called `admincli.properties`.

In spring boot I can simply place all properties in application.properties from where all properties are automatically picked and I inject them with `@Value` annotation at necessary places.

I have however used `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to run my spring application and not spring boot. Is there any way to easily read my `admincli.properties` and inject the same in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `getResourceAsStream`, it should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property place holder and load properties -
    @PropertySource("classpath:propertyFile.properties")
public class AppConfig {

```
 @Bean
 public static
 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer        
 propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ()
{
    return new        
     PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Then in the bean you can inject the property value by using @Value annotation-

```
private @Value("${propertyName}") String       
propertyField ;
```